# Translation of Excel INT to Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi

I am trying to translate an Excel sheet to Delphi and stumbled over the Excel INT.
Excel help say's INT rounds down (toward the negative infinity). 
The Excel cell is:

```
C13-(24*INT(C13/24))
```

Where C13 is initialized at -465.9862462 and calculates as 14.01375378

The best Delphi I can come up with is:

```
C13 := -465.9862462; 
RoundMode := GetRoundMode;// Save current mode
SetRoundMode(rmDown);
C13 := C13 - (24 * (Round(C13 / 24)));
SetRoundMode(RoundMode);// Restore mode
```

This produces the correct answer but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Delphi has an `Int()` function too. It is even documented:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Int

That would grossly be the equivalent of the Excel function. It also rounds down, but not towards negative infinity. It rounds down towards `0`. So for negative numbers, you would have to subtract `1.0`:

```
function ExcelInt(N: Extended): Extended;
begin
  Result := System.Int(N);
  if (Result <> N) and (N < 0.0) then
    Result := Result - 1.0;
end;
```

### Note:

One might be inclined to use `System.Math.Floor`, as that rounds down towards negative infinity already, but that returns an `Integer`, so for large values, you might get an integer overflow. Note that in Excel, every number is a `Double`, so its `INT()` returns a `Double` too.

Comment: Why on earth the delete request? Tsk, tsk, tsk.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Use `System.Math.Floor()` function, it is functionally the same as Excel `INT()` function.

---

From the [Excel documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef) for the `INT()` function we can read that 
`INT(number)` rounds the `number` argument (a real number) down to the nearest integer.
Ex. `INT(8.9)` retuns 8, `INT(-8.9)` returns -9

From the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Math.Floor) for the `System.Math.Floor()` function we can read that `Floor()` rounds the float type argument toward negative infinity and returns an integer.
Ex. `Floor(2.8) returns 2, Floor(-2.8) returns -3

Testing your function in Excel ( `C13-(24*INT(C13/24))` ) and in Delphi ( `C13 - (24 * Floor(C13 / 24))` ) both yield the same result of 14.0137538

Comment: Yes, for these values, i.e. in this particular case, it probably returns the right result. Generally, because Floor() returns an integer, it might not.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi equivalent is [`floor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Floor):

> Rounds variables toward negative infinity.

Comment: No, it isn't. Floor() returns an integer, while Int() returns a floating point value.

Comment: @Rudy, Excel docs say (for Int): *Rounds a number down to the nearest integer.*

Comment: @Rudy I don't see evidence to support your claim in the Excel documentation. I am not convinced that Excel maintains a distinction between floating point and integer types. Which makes your point rather moot.

Comment: To the nearest integer *value*.

Comment: OK, if it really rounds down to Excel's integers, then AFAICT, it rounds down to 16 bit integers. I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @David: If you must do a calculation in another langage that returns the same result, it does matter if a "number" is integer or float. If you do interop with Excel, it also matters.

Comment: @Ron: yes, I know what OP is talking about.

Comment: @rudy What makes you think that Excel functions return 16 bit integers?

Comment: @David: I used a table that probably showed old data types. It seems that Excel store all numbers as doubles. So Delphi's floor would be wrong, AFAICT.

Comment: @Rudy No it would not be wrong. Only if one was blinded by a false obsession with literal translation. Were one to have some imagination and translate the algorithm rather than the implementation then it would look a little different. Why be constrained by Excel's limitations?

Comment: Integers have a limited range, compared to doubles. So unless we know the exact numbers, and whether they stay in the integer range, it makes sense to translate literally, especially since it is not really very hard, using System.Int().

Comment: @Rudy This is tedious

Comment: @David: sometimes, things are tedious. <shrug>

Comment: FWIW, that is not an Excel limitation. It actually does what Floor() and Ceil() in Delphi should do too: return a Double.

Comment: @rudy not supporting integers is the limitation. floor and ceil are just fine.

Comment: What's with all the argument? Open Excel and test `1.23E+25` and `=INT(1.23E+25)`. The result in both cases is `1.23E+25`. Then in Delphi test `Floor(1.23E+25)` and `Int(1.23E+25)`. In fact also try a value larger than signed max but less than unsigned max for more insight. Both answers have their place, but depend on magnitude of numbers OP might have to deal with. If all numbers are 'small _enough_' then `Floor()` is clearly most practical.